# Density in the set of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S$ be the set of all rational numbers which are squares $x = p^2/q^2$ for some integers $p$ and $q$. How can I show that $S$ is dense in the set of non-negative real numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take any distinct $x , y \in \mathbb R$.  Assume without loss of generality that $x > y > 0$.  Then $\sqrt x > \sqrt y$, so by the density of $\mathbb Q$, $\sqrt x > r > \sqrt y$ for some $r \in \mathbb Q$.  So $x > r^2 > y$.